# How to disable a single aspx page in ASP.NET webapplication?

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

Would like to disable a single aspx page in an ASP.NET web application and show the message 'This page is under maintenance' while the application is still up. Is this possible?

Comment: Create a warning page containing the message, and then use URL Rewrite module or ASP.NET routing to block access on the page you want to disable and forward requests to the warning page.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that on `Application_BeginRequest` on `global.asax`. Check the if the specific file is called and show some other static page and End the process there. Here is how:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    string cTheFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);

    // if its the file you want to be offline
    if (cTheFileName == 'filename.aspx')
    {
        // the file we look now is the app_offline_alt.htm
        string cOffLineFile = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "app_offline_alt.htm";

        // if exist on root - if not we skip the offline mode.
        // this way you can put it offline with just the existing of this file.
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(cOffLineFile))
        {
            using (var fp = System.IO.File.OpenText(cOffLineFile))
            {
                // read it and send it to the browser
                app.Response.Write(fp.ReadToEnd());
                fp.Close();
            }

            // and stop the rest of processing
            app.Response.End();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

the `app_offline_alt.htm` contains a simple under maintenance message or what ever you like.